# Cleanest way to write prototype inheritance in JS

Tags: javascript, syntax, prototype

Somewhat of a JS newbie still, I'm trying to understand the best / cleanest way to use prototypes and inheritance.

Normally I write object/prototype definitions like this:

```
var Foo = function(data) {
  this.data = data;
};
Foo.prototype = {
  someMethod: function() {
    return "whatever";
  }
};
```

I like this because I often am using namespace objects a few layers deep, so it might actually look more like this:

```
App.Model.FooModel = function(){...};
App.Model.FooModel.prototype = {...};
```

This is nice because I don't have to type out the full name of every method to write the prototype, just the name, ie. `someMethod: function(){}` instead of `App.Model.FooModel.prototype.someMethod = function(){}`.

Now, the problem I've run into is I'm not sure how to do this with inheritance in JS. I can get inheritance working fine if I do it like this:

```
var Child = function(){...};
Child.prototype = new Parent;
Child.prototype.someMethod = function(){...};
```

...but now in a more complicated application we're back to writing out the full name of the object for every method, which I find both tedious and hard to read.

So, my question is: is there a clean, straightforward way to write prototypes that inherit from another object, except to attach all child methods using the full name of the object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this being javascript, you can always write your own:

```
function construct ( parent, fn, attr ) {
    fn.prototype = new parent();

    for (var x in attr) {
        fn.prototype[x] = attr[x];
    }
    return fn;
}
```

You can do the hasOwnProperty check if you want but the above is simplest implementation for clarity. This function encapsulates the three steps into one. You can now simply do:

```
var Foo = construct(
    Parent,
    function(data) {
        this.data = data;
    },
    {
        someMethod: function() {
            return "whatever";
        }
    }
);
```

If you don't like the syntax you can always come up with a better one. An alternative implementation is to simply implement the attr extension part and do the inheritance normally:

```
function extend (obj, attr) {
    for (var x in attr) {
        obj.prototype[x] = attr[x];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Again, simplified for clarity. So the syntax now becomes:

```
var Foo = function(){...};
Foo.prototype = new Parent;
extend(Foo.prototype,{
    someMethod : function(){...}
});
```

Comment: `class` is a reserved word, though `Class` isn't.

Comment: @gumballhead: Thanks, forgot about that. Changed class to constructor (which is more correct anyway since it returns the constructor)

Comment: Careful with `function constructor`, I believe you are shadowing `window.constructor` ... not that it necessarily matters, but someone could conceivably be storing things in `window.constructor`. Maybe the verb `construct` would be more appropriate.

Comment: What is window.constructor? Can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Ah, I see. The constructor property. Never heard of it before. Learn something new every day. Fixed now. Thanks @GGG

Comment: @slebetman technically it's a property of `window`'s prototype. That's pretty much the case with all JS objects... `({}).constructor == Object`, `({}).hasOwnProperty('constructor')` is false, `({}).__proto__.hasOwnProperty('constructor')` is true. `.constructor` holds a reference to the function that constructed the object, unless it's been manipulated.